# How to export unity games into react native?

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I was using the following package: @asmadsen/react-native-unity-view Link to show a unity game from my react native app.

This library has a component called UnityView which is responsible in showing the unity view of the game that we export from unity.

What my issue is: I want to add multiple unity games to my react native app. And I am unable to understand what should I do to make it work. Can any one tell how to export games into react native apps in detailed way.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: the repository seems to have a quite complete documentation about how to carry that out along with some code snippets. Have you tried following that [documentation](https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view)  ?

Comment: Yes tried this one as well